# Is the dual of the dual curve the original curve?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

In algebraic geometry, is the dual of the dual curve the original curve? Why or why not?

Comment: This is a very classical result, true for hypersurfaces of any dimension; you'll find a proof in many places, including Chapter 1 of Dolgachev's book. MO is a site for questions about mathematics at research level, please consider using math.stackexchange.com instead.

Comment: Since the OP did not specify the ground field, I should point out that this is not always true in positive characteristic. A simple counterexample is of a conic in characteristic two. The dual is a line and the double dual a point.

Comment: Dolgachev's book does not have a proof. Theorem 1.2.2, the reflexivity theorem, is not proven.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is claimed and proved as Theorem 1 here https://math.berkeley.edu/~monks/papers/DualityV3.pdf